# Pywinauto keyboard not recognizing double letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, pywinauto, pywin

I am trying to type shortcut `ALT + C + C`, but only takes first letter `ALT + C` which in code translates:

```
processId = 0
try:
    app.connect(process=processId)
except:
    print("issue not found")
win = app.window(top_level_only=False, visible_only=False, found_index=0)
winUia = win.wrapper_object()
winUia.type_keys("{VK_MENU down}CC{VK_MENU up}", set_foreground=True, pause=.5, vk_packet=False, with_spaces=True)
```

Comment: I would recommend you do the sequence twice with a single C and see if that works as you expect.

Comment: @Jarvis How would that be?

Comment: How as in what I mean? Or how as in the code?

Comment: `”{VK_MENU down}C{VK_MENU up}{VK_MENU down}C{VK_MENU up}”` is what I was suggesting… also you could try either method with lowercase c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it like

```
winUia.type_keys("{VK_MENU down}(CC 2){VK_MENU up}", set_foreground=True, pause=.5, vk_packet=False, with_spaces=True)
```

Comment: Interesting, is the `(CC 2)` standard syntax for getting it to do an entry multiple times?

Comment: This is what I tried and worked